# Given the integral of an equation over one set of bounds find the integral over another set of bounds.

Tags: integration, derivatives, summation

If $\int_{1}^{3}f(w)dw=7$, find the value of $\int_{1}^{2}f(5-2x)dx=7$

I think this problem has something to do with the fact that (5-2(2)) = 1 and (5-2(1)) = 3 and these are the bound of the original integral, but I'm not sure how to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u = 5-2x, du = -2dx \to I = \dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle \int_{1}^{3} f(u)du= \dfrac{7}{2}$

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was some kind of relation there.

Comment: But so much more... pleasurable... to be served...

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

You can let $\omega=5-2x$. Can you proceed from here?